# How can I display only months in dhtmlxGantt?

Tags: dhtmlx

I'm using dhtmlxGantt but my project is VERY long and I only would only like to display the months without the days and also display the years...How could I do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind got it...

gantt.config.scale_unit = "month"; 
gantt.config.date_scale = "%Y-%M";